# Excel / Copy paste 2 Columns into one using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, copy-paste

I'm really new in powershell and I try to write a script to help me in copying 2 or more columns and paste it into only one with a particular format.

What I want is something like that :

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQnKp.png)

It's been 2 days I looked for the correct syntax and I can't find it

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I try to learn how excel and powershell works ( I started 1 week ago so I don't know anything )
I found a script to copy/paste some columns. I understand how it works but know I would like to paste these columns into only one ( like I said )

Here is the script I have :

```
$ExcelPath = ''
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item(“lolo”)
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item(“lala”)

$worksheet.activate()
$lastRow1 = $worksheet.UsedRange.rows.count
$range1 = $worksheet.Range("A2:C$lastRow1")
$range1.copy()

$worksheet2.activate()
$lastRow2 = $worksheet2.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
$range2 = $worksheet2.Range("A$($lastRow2)")
$worksheet2.Paste($range2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data to CSV by example. After it depends what you want to do, if you want to include null  properties or not ...

```
Import-Csv -Path filepath | Select-Object -Properties *, @{"l"="Col4", e={ "`"$($_.Col1)`", `"$($_.Col2)`",`"$($_.Col3)`",`"`",`"`"" } } | Export-CSV -Path outputpath -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```